Why is cmake removing my `-march` switch?
I am cross-compiling with cmake, creating libfoo.a from C file foo.c. This directory, and the CMakeLists.txt only deal with libfoo.a.
My CMakeLists.txt looks like this...
add_library(foo  STATIC  foo.c)
set_source_files_properties(foo.c
  PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_OPTIONS "-Wall;-Wextra;-pedantic;-Werror;-march=armv8-a+sve"
)

or like this...
add_library(foo  STATIC  foo.c)
target_compile_options(foo
  PUBLIC
    "-Wall;-Wextra;-pedantic;-Werror;-march=armv8-a+sve"
)

or variants with add_compile_options(), removing -Wall, etc...
When I look in the generated compile_commands.json, I can see that cmake has stripped out the -march=armv8-a+sve switch.  How can I get it to not do that?  How can I get -march to remain?
I'm using cmake version 3.28.0 although I've also tried version 3.30.5. They act the same.
I don't think it matters, but my CMAKE_C_COMPILER is .../gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc.
Edit:
This project does not use a toolchain file.
The generated flags.make in the cmake build directory DOES add my -march=armv8-a+sve switch to the C_FLAGS variable.  I believe that cmake is compiling my file correctly, but I was misled by the incorrectly generated compile_commands.json which is done by CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.
Edit 2:
Using Ninja makes fewer infrastructure files, so it is more clear what is going on.
There is still a problem...  My local march is propagated back to other compilations from other directories, even though my command is target specific.
I need to spend more time to understand this mess...  Sorry!

Do you use a toolchain file for your cross-compilation? Normally, options like -march are declared in the toolchain, as files compiled without these options won't produce a binary code which will be suitable for the target platform. Also, have you checked whether actual compilation of the foo.c uses your -march option? (CMake doesn't use file compile_commands.json, this file is generated only for outer usage.)

Unfortunately @Tsyvarev, this project does not use a toolchain file (despite my earlier suggestion to do so!)
I'll edit in some more information above...
